# Como modificar uma Label ao escrever no Entry em tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Gostaria de fazer um programa que detecta a mudança no texto da Entry e muda o Label para o mesmo texto da Entry, como eu posso fazer isto?

```
from tkinter import *

# Configurações da Tela
window = Tk()
window.title("Hello World")  
window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
window.geometry("300x300")

TextoLabel = StringVar()
TextoLabel.set("AAAAAA")
#Criando uma funcao para dar update na Label


# Widgets
entrada = Entry(window)
lbl = Label(textvariable = TextoLabel)
b = Button(text="see ya?!")

# Mostrar todos os itens na tela
b.pack()
entrada.pack()
lbl.pack()
window.mainloop()

while True:
    if entryname.get() == "":
        TextoLabel.set("Nada")
        window.update_idletasks()
    else:
        TextoLabel.set(entryname.get())
        window.update_idletasks()
```

Comment: Fiz uma modificação, mas mesmo assim continua não funcionando. Ela é http://pastebin.com/ntFJKPDJ

Answer (score 1):

Para começar, desaconselho usar loops em tkinter, porque vão interferir com o *mainloop*.

O que queres fazer pode-se fazer pelo menos em duas maneiras:

1. Usar o mesmo objeto `StringVar` seja para o objeto `Entry` seja para o `Label`, o que é simples quanto o seguinte:

   ```
   from tkinter import *


   root = Tk()

   prompt = Label(root, text="Insere algo")
   prompt.pack(side="left")

   entry_content = StringVar()

   # Associando "entry_content" a propriedade "textvariable".
   # O que escreves no "entry" é "absorvido" pelo "entry_content"

   entry = Entry(root, textvariable=entry_content) 
   entry.pack(side="left")

   # O valor do "entry_content" é modificado no "entry"
   # E essa modificação vai-se refletir nesta "label"    

   label = Label(root, text="", textvariable=entry_content)
   label.pack(side="left")

   root.mainloop()
   ```
2. Não usar um objecto `StringVar`, mas associar uma chamada a uma função com o certo evento, neste caso o evento é `<KeyRelease>`, que praticamente acontece quando deixas de carregar uma tecla. Nesta função podes tipo controlar o conteúdo da Label e confronta-lo com o conteúdo da Entry.

   ```
   from tkinter import *


   root = Tk()

   prompt = Label(root, text="Insere algo")
   prompt.pack(side="left")

   entry = Entry(root)
   entry.pack(side="left")


   def on_key_pressing(event, entry, label):
       print(entry.get(), label.cget("text"))
       if entry.get() != label.cget("text"):
           label.config(text=entry.get())

   # Associando o evento <Key> com a chamada
   # a funcão on_key_pressing
   entry.bind("<KeyRelease>", lambda e: on_key_pressing(e, entry, label))

   label = Label(root, text="")
   label.pack(side="left")

   root.mainloop()
   ```

Se não percebes algo, pergunta nos comentários, e eu edito a resposta ;)